# What am I doing wrong? Partial Fraction Decomp.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\int\frac{1-v}{(v+1)^2}dv$$

> I think I am supposed to do PFD, but solving for A and B I get zero for both.

$$(1-v) = A(v+1) + B(v+1)$$

> let $v = -1$

$$A = \frac{2}{0}, B = \frac{2}{0}$$

> So this is undefined? (or infinity?)

Comment: Hint:  write 1 - v as 2 - (v+1).

Comment: Hmm so B = 2 A = -1?

Comment: Your form isn't a good one.  As you point out, solving for A and B in your expression isn't going to work.  There are other forms that work, but in this case a direct attack works just fine...and that's what my hint pointed at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re interested in the integration rather than the abstract partial fraction problem, you should make the substitution $u=v+1$, giving
$$
\int\frac{(2-u)du}{u^2}=\int\Big(2u^{-2}-\frac1u\Big)du\,,
$$
then make the backward substitution after doing your simple integration.

Comment: This is the best way because it avoids PFD.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

When the denominator has multiple roots, the method changes a bit. Try
$$\frac A{v+1}+\frac B{(v+1)^2}=\frac{1-v}{(v+1)^2}$$